# SocialSharing Plugin not working in MFP 6.3, jdk 1.8 and Android 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Environment - jdk 1.8, MobileFirst Platform -6.3, sdk set to 24 for andorid 7.0 build.We are migrating our project to make apk work in android 7.0 due to which we are updating our worklight server from 6.2 to MobileFirst Platform 6.3.Also updated jdk to 1.8 and set sdk to 24.config.xml file in android environment includes SocialSharing plugin. While running my build script I am getting following error,

```
Compiling 13 source files to C:\c2cProject6.3\repository\nx_c2c_live_phase1_delivery\tmp_nxlive_builds\nx_c2c_live_build_development_20170309_043615\worklight\source\nx_c2c_live\apps\nx_c2c_live_passenger\android\native\bin\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] C:\c2cProject6.3\repository\nx_c2c_live_phase1_delivery\tmp_nxlive_builds\nx_c2c_live_build_development_20170309_043615\worklight\source\nx_c2c_live\apps\nx_c2c_live_passenger\android\native\src\nl\xservices\plugins\SocialSharing.java:19: error: package org.apache.http.util does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;



<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
          id        = "nx_c2c_live_passenger"
          version   = "1.0.0.0">
      <name>nx_c2c_live_passenger</name>

      <feature name="SocialSharing">
          <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing"/>
      </feature>

</widget>
```

Any help appreciated to resolve compilation issue?

Comment: It appears you have a Cordova plugin "SocialSharing" ? If so, you should add all the dependencies it requires.